# Can't figure out how to accurately make two API Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Twitch.tv app as part of the [FCC](https://www.freecodecamp.com) course. I'm near the finish line but I'm struggling to get the logo for each user. To explain, there's two different links for the API where I can get data: Streams & Channels.

If I use the streams link I can only get the logo if the user is online (which isn't really any good), where as with Channel I can get it regardless. To get what's streaming though, I really need to use the Stream link. The outcome then I guess, is I need to use both.

I've tried a variety of ways to make one call to streams and one to channels for the logo with a load of different results and I really can't figure it out. The latest way I've tried (below) gets me logos but not the correct stream/streamer data. I'm guessing the issue is how I'm nesting the calls within one another, but I can't figure out the proper way to do it.

Would appreciate any help anyone can give. Here's my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/woftis/pen/yJzXJa) where you can see the full code.

```
function apicall(streamer) {
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + streamer, function(a) {
    if (a.stream == null) {
      stateclass = 'bg-danger';
      game = 'Offline';
      status = '';
      url = '';
    } else {
      stateclass = 'bg-success';
      game = a.stream.game + ': ';
      status = a.stream.channel.status;
      url = '<a target="_blank" href="' + a.stream.channel.url + '">';
    }
    who = streamer;
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + streamer, function(b) {
      logo = b.logo;
      console.log(logo);

      html += '<div class ="row ' + stateclass + '"><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="' + logo + '"></div><div class="col-xs-4">' + who + '</div>' + '<div class="col-xs-6">' + url + game + status + '</a></div></div>';
      $(".options").html(html);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

```
function apicall(streamer) {
  var streamsReq = $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + streamer);
  var channelsReq = $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + streamer);

  return $.when(streamsReq, channelsReq).done(function (streams, channels) {
    var stateclass, link, html = '';

    if (streams.stream && streams.stream.cannel) {
      stateclass = 'bg-success';
      link = '<a target="_blank" href="' + streams.stream.channel.url + '">' + 
        streams.stream.game + ': ' + streams.stream.channel.status + '</a>';
    } else {
      stateclass = 'bg-danger';
      link = 'Offline';
    }

    html += '<div class ="row ' + stateclass + '">';
    html += '<div class="col-xs-2"><img src="' + channels.logo + '"></div>';
    html += '<div class="col-xs-4">' + streamer + '</div>';
    html += '<div class="col-xs-6">' + link + '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    $(".options").html(html);
  }).fail(function () {
    // add error handling
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check out the documentation you attached. I tried the code attached but it doesn't seem to be working; any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at the browser's console?

Comment: Yes but only message I'm getting is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - which I think is something to do with CodePen and links. I only seem to be getting one result from the API call. You can see it here: http://codepen.io/woftis/pen/yJzXJa

Comment: Try `$(".options").append(html);`

Comment: That fixes the issue with the content being over-written. Unfortunately, it looks like the API is not returning any data, but I can't puzzle out why.

Comment: The API returns data for me, even with your codepen example.